# String index out of range error?

Tags: python, string, indexing

Hello I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding why the string index is listed as 'out of range.' Consider the string which I'm trying to translate in this code:

```
a = str("g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.")
b = 0
while True:
    if a[b] == str("k"): 
        a.replace("k", "m")
        b = b + 1 #Methodically checks each string for a 'k' and replaces it with a 'm'
    elif a[b] == str("o"):
        a.replace("o", "q")
        b = b + 1#Checks for an 'o' and replaces with 'q'
    elif a[b] == str("e"):
        a.replace("e", "g")
        b = b + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1
        continue
        if b == 202:
            print(a)
            break
```

Comment: You don't need to turn strings into strings here (just use `== 'k'`).

Comment: Ah, good old python challenge!

Comment: `a.replace(...)` is a no op.... So I imagine your counts will be incorrect

Answer (score 4):

You never reach your `break` statement at the end of the loop, because you hit the `continue` first and jump to the next iteration. Just take out the `continue` and you should be all set.

```
else:
    b = b + 1
    if b == 202:
        print(a)
        break
```

---

I'd also advise against using "magic" numbers like `202` here. Instead, determine dynamically whether you're at the end of the string, using the `len` function:

```
if b == len(a)-1:
    break
```

Or even better, take advantage of the fact that you can easily iterate over strings in Python:

```
for ch in a:
    # Do stuff
```

---

As others have said in the comments, your logic is also flawed (`replace` will just go over the whole string anyway!), and you don't need all those `str(...)` calls in there. Your whole function could be rewritten as:

```
newstring = ''
for ch in a:
    if ch == 'k':
        newstring += 'm'
    elif ch == 'o':
        newstring += 'q'
    elif ch == 'e':
        newstring += 'g'
    else:
        newstring += ch
print newstring
```

Or even better, just use the `replace` function the way it's meant to be used:

```
print a.replace('k', 'm').replace('o', 'q').replace('e','g')
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a "continue" before the breaking "if" comparison. so it probably never gets to the if , and it will never break

Answer (score 0):

String is a sequence in python, you can iterate over it.

Secondly as strings are immutable so `str.replace` doesn't modifies `a`, it simply returns a new string.

```
a = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

for char in a:      
    if char == "k":
        a = a.replace("k", "m")  #assign the new string back to `a`
    elif char == "o":
        a = a.replace("o", "q")
    elif char == "e":
        a = a.replace("e", "g")
print a
```

Comment: @EfeEsenwa use `a = a.replace("k", "m")`, it'll reassign the new string back to `a`. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Your `continue` is continuing the loop such that the `if b == 202` statement is never reached.

Try this:

```
a = str("g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.")
b = 0
while True:
    if a[b] == str("k"):
        a.replace("k", "m")
        b = b + 1
    elif a[b] == str("o"):
        a.replace("o", "q")
        b = b + 1
    elif a[b] == str("e"):
        a.replace("e", "g")
        b = b + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1
        #continue
    if b == 202:
        print(a)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not breaking out of the loop.

```
else:
    b = b + 1
    continue
    if b == 202:
        print a
        break
```

You only do the test if you get to the else and not every time. **Unindent the last 3 lines of your code** to get it working. **If you still are getting a problem** that's because you have continue in the else clause: remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you reach the `continue`, the `if b == 202` statement is never reached.

However, `s.replace(old, new)` replaces ALL occurrences of `old` with `new`, so you don't need to iterate over it:

```
a = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

a = a.replace('k', 'm')
a = a.replace('o', 'q')
a = a.replace('e', 'g')
```

However, this is tedious. You create a dictionary of replacements:

```
replacements = {'k': 'm', 'o': 'q', 'e': 'g'}
for old, new in replacements.items():
    a = a.replace(old, new)
```

Alternatively, you can just create two lists and `zip` them:

```
olds, news = ['k', 'o', 'e'], ['m', 'q', 'g']
for old, new in zip(olds, news):
    a = a.replace(old, new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, the Pythonic way of writing your code (if I'm understanding its intent properly) is:

```
from string import maketrans
if len(a) >= 202:
    print a[:202].translate(maketrans('koe', 'mqg')) + a[202:]
```

Although I suspect `b` was just being to check you were at the end of the string, so probably just:

```
print a.translate(maketrans('koe', 'mqg'))
```